# Automating Powershell script by using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a User Creation AD script which adds users automatically.

For the moment the script is ok, but i expect that the script has to be modified in the future.

For example i want to change this script:

```
 <Departments>
  <Department>Finance</Department>
  <Department>IT</Department>
  <Department>Marketing</Department>
  <Department>Sales</Department>
  <Department>Executive</Department>
  <Department>Human Resources</Department>
  <Department>Security</Department>
 </Departments>
```

to

```
 <Departments>
  <Department>Finance</Department>
  <Department>IT</Department>
  <Department>Marketing</Department>
  <Department>Sales</Department>
  <Department>Executive</Department>
  <Department>Human Resources</Department>
  <Department>Security</Department>
  <Department>Intern</Department>
 </Departments>
```

So i want to add a line in the existing Powershell script, using another Powershell script.

This is just an example. In the future i want add a lot of code.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Why would you want to create a script, that edit another script in order for it to run..? Just create one script with multiple possibilities/outcomes?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  You might want to look into Advanced Functions and ParameterSets.

Comment: Why? Modifying a powershell script with a script is a bad idea. So much that can go wrong. Abort mission.

Comment: In the example, you are modifying an XML file, not a PowerShell script.  Is this about modifying XML or a PowerShell script?